# Error in the building process when trying to deploy on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, deployment, vercel

I'm encountering a problem while trying to deploy a little project in Next.JS on Vercel.  In the process of building it display these errors[the errors displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTikG.png) ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTikG.png)

Here is the code of the page.tsx file:

```
export default function Page() {
    return <p>Customers Page</p>;
  }
```

How can I do to correct these errors?

I tried to change the position of the letters, spacing between them in the file but it has changed nothing.

Comment: Did you define the type like this https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page